bluetooth is not running ... failed
I need help to solve this problem.
I'm trying to solve the problem that on my Linux, wlan0 and wlan1 are not being displayed.
So I saw in a group that it would be necessary to install Bluetooth, I saw that it really wasn't installed, I installed it and when I load compat-wireless-2010-10-10 giving the make load command, the error below occurs, what do I need to do? I've been trying to fix this for 2 days.
$ make load
/home/dragonices/Downloads/compat-wireless-2010-10-10/config.mk:196: "WARNING: CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT will be deactivated or not working because kernel was compiled with CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT=n. Tools using wext interface like iwconfig will not work. To activate it build your kernel e.g. with CONFIG_LIBIPW=m."
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
Stoping bluetooth service..
Stopping bluetooth: /usr/sbin/bluetoothd.
bluetooth is not running ... failed!
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
/sbin/modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
Loading ipw2100...
modprobe: FATAL: Module ipw2100 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading ipw2200...
modprobe: FATAL: Module ipw2200 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading libertas_cs...
modprobe: FATAL: Module libertas_cs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading usb8xxx...
modprobe: FATAL: Module usb8xxx not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading p54pci...
modprobe: FATAL: Module p54pci not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading p54usb...
modprobe: FATAL: Module p54usb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading adm8211...
modprobe: FATAL: Module adm8211 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading zd1211rw...
modprobe: FATAL: Module zd1211rw not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading rtl8180...
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8180 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading rtl8187...
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8187 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading p54pci...
modprobe: FATAL: Module p54pci not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading p54usb...
modprobe: FATAL: Module p54usb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading iwl3945...
modprobe: FATAL: Module iwl3945 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading iwlagn...
modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlagn not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading ath...
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading ar9170usb...
modprobe: FATAL: Module ar9170usb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading rtl8180...
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8180 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading rtl8187...
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8187 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading rt2400pci...
modprobe: FATAL: Module rt2400pci not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading rt2500pci...
modprobe: FATAL: Module rt2500pci not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading rt61pci...
modprobe: FATAL: Module rt61pci not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading rt2500usb...
modprobe: FATAL: Module rt2500usb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading rt73usb...
modprobe: FATAL: Module rt73usb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading rndis_wlan...
modprobe: FATAL: Module rndis_wlan not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading at76_usb...
modprobe: FATAL: Module at76_usb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading mwl8k...
modprobe: FATAL: Module mwl8k not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading mac80211_hwsim...
modprobe: FATAL: Module mac80211_hwsim not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading at76c50x_usb...
modprobe: FATAL: Module at76c50x_usb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading bluetooth...
modprobe: FATAL: Module bluetooth not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading btusb...
modprobe: FATAL: Module btusb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading l2cap...
modprobe: FATAL: Module l2cap not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading sco...
modprobe: FATAL: Module sco not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading hidp...
modprobe: FATAL: Module hidp not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading rfcomm...
modprobe: FATAL: Module rfcomm not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Loading bnep...
modprobe: FATAL: Module bnep not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
./scripts/load.sh: line 21: athload: command not found
./scripts/load.sh: line 23: b43load: command not found
Starting bluetooth service..
Starting bluetooth: bluetoothd.
bluetooth is running.


This is very confusing and likely a X-Y problem. It seems your having trouble with WiFi in your Ubuntu. If so, please [edit] the question and say exactly that and include your Ubuntu release/version and your WiFi (or WiFi+Bluetooth) chipset - either lspci (for internal) or lsusb (for USB external) commands will identify the WiFi device, make sure to copy/paste here the full line identifying it -, NOT what you think is a solution - "I saw in a group that it would be necessary to install Bluetooth" certainly ISN'T ...

... nor is installing random stuff from the internet. Solutions are always hardware dependent.

The error messages contain the path /lib/modules/5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2. Does than mean the issue is attempting to use Bluetooth in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)? There is the open issue Bluetooth not supported (Built-in and USB-BT Adapter) on the Microsoft GitHub project used to report WSL issues.

Could you clarify what led you to try installing Bluetooth? From what you've written so far I cannot see why you thought that was the solution. Were you trying to add Bluetooth to begin with, or were you just looking for wireless network device access? Is a WSL system, another sort of VM, or is Ubuntu installed directly to hardware? Please give us more details about your system, the problem you're facing, and some more details about the research and what you've tried, and add that info to the question itself.
